# Is there a private key of an ICO/Contract?

Tags: tokens, contract-deployment, etherscan, private-key

I have deployed my contract on the main net, is there any private key of that address? If yes, where can I find it?

Thanks, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, contract owner will have private key of his address only but contract has no private keys